# Javascript why console.log(typeof "Not a Number" - "Number") prints 'NaN'?

Tags: javascript, types, nan, typeof

I know and acknowledge that

```js
console.log(typeof NaN) // 'number'
```

however I need help understanding the logic of

```js
console.log(typeof "Not a Number" - "Number") // 'NaN'
```

Looking at this

```js
console.log("NaN is normal" - "normal" + "special") // NaNspecial
```

I see that `"NaN is normal" - "normal"` gives `NaN` (which is a `number` type) which then get's converted to a `string` before concatenation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). `typeof` has a precedence of 17, and subtraction has a precedence of 14. So

```
console.log(typeof "Not a Number" - "Number") // 'NaN'
```

is equivalent to:

```
console.log(typeof "Not a Number" - "Number") // original line
console.log((typeof "Not a Number") - "Number") // grouping; operator precedence
console.log(("string") - "Number")
console.log("string" - "Number")
// A string can't be meaningfully subtracted from another string, so the result is NaN
console.log(NaN)
```

Similarly, `-` and `+` have the same precedence, and work left-to-right, so the final code is equivalent to:

```
console.log("NaN is normal" - "normal" + "special") // original line
console.log(("NaN is normal" - "normal") + "special")
console.log((NaN) + "special")
// NaN gets coerced to a string and concatenated:
console.log("NaNspecial")
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the explanation I was missing.